# Time complexity and Big-O notation specific question

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

A question in one of my past exams is a multi-choice question:

```
Choose the FALSE statement: 7(log n) + 5n + n(log log n) + 3n(ln n) is

A. O(n^2)
B. Ω(n^2)
C. O(n log^2 n)
D. Ω(n)
E. Θ(n log n)
```

First I concluded that the running time of the algorithm had to be Θ(n log n), which ruled out option E. I then concluded that Option B, Ω(n^2), ws false, because I knew that Θ(n log n) was smaller than Θ(n^2), therefore Ω(n^2) could not be true. So I thought B would be the answer.

But I also realised that C couldn't be true either, since Θ(n log n) is a larger running time than Θ(n log^2 n). But it couldn't possibly be 2 of the answers correct.

So which is correct: is it B? or is it C? or neither? I'm so confused. :S

Comment: But isn't Θ(n log n) is a larger running time than Θ(n log^2 n)?

Comment: no, O(nlogn) < O(nlog^2(n)) it is NOT log(log(n)) but log(n)*log(n), and log(n)*log(n) > log(n) for every n>2

Comment: Owow thanks amit your comment cleared it up completely. I gotta remember that n(log^2 n) != n(log log n). Thanks muchly! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the false statement is `omega(n^2)`.

it is exactly `theta(nlogn)` (since 3n(ln n)) is the "highest", and it is `theta(nlogn)`.

`omega(n^2)` says it is not better then n^2 complexity, which is false in here.

addition: in your example the following is true:

7(log n) < 5n <  n(log log n) < 3n(ln n) 

7logn = theta(logn), 5n = theta(n), n(loglogn) = theta (nloglog(n)), 3nln(n) = theta(nlogn)

which as said, (nlogn) is the highest, thus: 

`7(log n) + 5n +  n(log log n) + 3n(ln n)  = theta(nlogn)`

 and all are o(n^2) (small o here on purpose), so Omega(n^2) is the false statement.

**EDIT:** clarifying and adding what I've wrote in comments:

option C is True because O(nlogn) < O(nlog^2(n)). mathematically: 

`nlog^2(n) = n*log(n)*log(n) > n*log(n)` for every n>2.

example: for n=1,000,000: `nlogn = 1,000,000*20 = 20,000,000` 

while `n*log^2(n) = 1,000,000*20*20=400,000,000`.

Comment: But what about option C? Option C is false as well, isn't it?

Comment: no, option C is true, since O(nlog^2(n))> O(nlogn) for example: n=1,000,000, nlogn = 1,000,000*20 = 20,000,000 while nlog^2(n) is 1,000,000*20*20 = 400,000,000. note that big O means that the solution is "not worth then", which is true in here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that log is the base 2 logarithm and ln is the natural logarithm, the following statement is true:

> Θ(log(*n*))  <  Θ(*n*·log(log(*n*)))  <  Θ(*n*)  <  Θ(*n*·ln(*n*))

So the overall complexity is Θ(*n*·ln(*n*)).

Now let’s check the statements:

- *n*·ln(*n*) ∈ O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) is **true**

  > *n*·ln(*n*) ≤ *c*·‍*n*<sup>2</sup> for *c* = 1, ‍∀*n* ≥ 0
- *n*·ln(*n*) ∈ Ω(*n*<sup>2</sup>) is **false**

  > *n*·ln(*n*) ≱ *n*<sup>2</sup> hence ln(*n*) < *c*·*n* for *c* = 1, ‍∀*n* ≥ 0
- *n*·ln(*n*) ∈ O(*n*·(log(*n*))<sup>2</sup>) is **true**

  > *n*·(log(*n*))<sup>2</sup> = *n*·(ln(*n*)/ln(2))<sup>2</sup> = *n*·(ln(*n*))<sup>2</sup>/(ln(2))<sup>2</sup> and *n*·ln(*n*) ≤ *c*·‍*n*·(ln(*n*))<sup>2</sup>/(ln(2))<sup>2</sup> for *c* = (ln(2))<sup>2</sup>, ∀*n* ≥ e
- *n*·ln(*n*) ∈ Ω(*n*) is **true**

  > *n*·ln(*n*) ≥ *c*·‍*n* for *c* = 1, ∀*n* ≥ 0
- *n*·ln(*n*) ∈ Θ(*n*·log(*n*)) is **true**

  > *n*·log(*n*) = *n*·ln(*n*)/ln(2) and *n*·ln(*n*) = *c*·‍*n*·ln(*n*)/ln(2) for *c* = ln(2), ∀*n* ≥ 0

Comment: regarding the assumption on first line: it does not matter which base the logarithm is, because logm(n) = O(logk(n)) for every m,k. logm(n) = logk(n)/logk(m) = logk(n)/CONST = O(log(n))